# Is it possible to build the prediction matrix (Kalman Filter) based on these input data (x,y, velocity)? I don't have x, y components of the velocity

Tags: kalman-filter

I try to build equations of motion (prediction matrix), I have this input data: GPS (x, y) and velocity. Is it possible to build the prediction matrix? The problem is that I don't have the x, y components of the velocity.

My approach is:

> p(k) = p(k−1) + Δt(vk−1)
>
> v(k) =          v(k−1)

the matrix would be:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & Δt \\
0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).